# how to retrieve value of 'Position' from SHOW MASTER STATUS in mariadb

Tags: docker, mariadb, master-slave

How can I retrieve just the 'position' value from the 'SHOW MASTER STATUS' query expression in MariaDB(running in docker container) from outside the docker container ?

Something like, I have the following :-

```
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File              | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| master-bin.000003 |      375 |              |                  |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

and need to get only value of position using bash script ?

Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Vineet so your MariaDB instance is running in a docker container and you want to access it via a shell script that is outside the container. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Ashok, Yes my MariaDB instance running inside docker container, and just I want to retrieve value of 'Position' from "SHOW MASTER STATUS" from outside the container. When I tried with :- mysql -uroot -pabc123 -e "SHOW MASTER STATUS" | awk '{print $2}' , from inside the docker container, it is working fine. But, when I tried this from outside the container, then I get both values of 'File' and 'Position' in one line, but I need to get only the value of 'Position'. Please help

Comment: Are you using any she'll script to login into the container from outside?

Comment: Yes Ashok.. I'm using the following command :- docker exec -it mariadb bash ,, to access into the MariaDB container from outside

Comment: Please help to share your shell script

Comment: I'm bringing up my docker container using docker run command and then using docker exec command to access to docker container. Like this way :- `docker run -itd -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -name mariadb -d mariadb:10.5.5` to create and start docker container and then `docker exec -it mariadb bash`  to access it from outside. But still not able to retrieve single value from `show master status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When MariaDB running inside docker container and want to retrieve File and Position Value from "SHOW MASTER STATUS" in MariaDB/MySQL from outside the docker container, use the following command in bash :-

**for File**

```
docker exec -it <mariadb_container_name> bash -c "mysql -u<username> -p<password> -Ne 'show master status' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f1"
```

**for Position**

```
docker exec -it <mariadb_container_name> bash -c "mysql -u<username> -p<password> -Ne 'show master status' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f2"
```